# Using jQuery-ui autocomplete variables in further jQuery-ui autocomplete functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

How can I use the selected item from a jQuery-ui autocomplete in a further jQuery-ui autocomplete function?

e.g. for this HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="project">Project: </label>
    <input id="project" />
    <label for="phase">Phase: </label>
    <input id="phase" />
    <label for="filename">Project: </label>
    <input id="filename" />
</div>
```

I am using the following autocomplete function with a JSON endpoint to supply the data.

```
$(function() {
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
    source: baseUrl+"json/listtitles",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    }
});
});
```

Then in this second autocomplete I want to take the selected value from the first autocomplete function and use it to build the URL string for use in the source attribute of a second autocomplete (shown here as valueFromFirstAutocomplete).

```
$(function() {
$( "#phase" ).autocomplete({
    source: baseUrl+"json/listphases/"+valueFromFirstAutocomplete,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize the source option with a callback, adding the additonal parameter to the URL:

```
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
    source: baseUrl+"json/listtitles",
    minLength: 2
});
$( "#phase" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.get(baseUrl + "/json/listphases/" + $("#project").val(), request, response);
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm after but I'm not managing to get it to work.  It appears that the source function is not getting called. Or at least is not printing my debug statement:

Comment: Ignore that comment. Its working fine. I was being a fool. Many thanks Jörn!

Answer (score 0):

You could just put one inside the other....

Is there some reason this won't work?

```
$(function() {
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
    source: baseUrl+"json/listtitles",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
       $(function() {
       $( "#phase" ).autocomplete({
           source: baseUrl+"json/listphases/"+ui.item.value,
           minLength: 2,
           select: function( event, ui ) {
           }
       });
       });
    }
});
});
```

To use these independently you could do something like this:

```
var funclist = {
    populate1 : function() {
      $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
        source: baseUrl+"json/listtitles",
        minLength: 2,
        select: populate2;
      },

   populate2 : function(event,ui) {
      $( "#phase" ).autocomplete({
        source: baseUrl+"json/listphases/"+ui.item.value,
        minLength: 2,
        select: populate3;
     }
   populate3 : ; // etc
}

$(funclist.populate1);
```

Comment: That looks like it may work, but I may want to use each autocomplete function independently so wrapping them inside each other might not be the best approach. Is this a case of variable scope? Should I declare 3 variables outside of the functions to hold the values and update them from within the functions?

Comment: maybe, see change about how to use independently